# Navbar not responsive on iPad, what to do?

Tags: css, ipad, responsive-design, navbar

I'm trying to figure out how to make the navbar at my site http://lundinskatt.se to resize on an iPad Mini just like it does on a smaller screen like Google Nexus 7. The way it shows now is that the whole menu "jumps" down and positions itself under the logo. I just want it to be responsive like on the smaller screens.

I'm sure this is an easy fix but my brain isn't working with me today so I've got to ask any of you guys if you know what I should do??

Best Regards
Evelina

Comment: Please include the minimal necessary code to reproduce your issue *in the question itself*. Your question will be completely useless to others once you fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

According to your css you have

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="fav-nav-sm">
                <div class="row-fluid"> 
                    <div id="fav-nav" class="span12">
                        <div class="navigation">
                            <div class="moduletable_menu"><ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/">Hem</a></li><li class="item-107"><a href="/verksamhetsomraden">Verksamhetsområden</a></li><li class="item-108"><a href="/abonnemang">Abonnemang</a></li><li class="item-110"><a href="/nyheter">Nyheter</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="/kontakt">Kontakt</a></li></ul>
</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is for medium screens -because if you look at your css

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

    #fav-nav-sm {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
  #fav-header #fav-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #fav-nav-sm #fav-nav {
    padding: 7px 0px 16px;
    float: none;
  }
  #fav-nav-sm .moduletable ul.nav.menu { 
    float: none; 
  }
  #fav-nav-sm .navigation {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #fav-nav-sm .navigation .nav-pills {
    margin-top: 0;
  }

}
```

These are all the properties you are setting on this menu between the above mentioned breakpoints.

From your question you want to have either desktop layout of menu or mobile layout(medium screens not needed-remove the markup in html and respective styling from css keeps your code clean as well).

Now that this menu is gone you want to show hamburger menu on top of the logo.

change your query on line 402 and 1085 to this query

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {

}
```